# Seven Segment Display outputs are unknown

Tags: verilog, fpga, vivado, seven-segment-display

I'm trying to make a counter that counts from 0-9 and displays on my Nexys A7's seven segment display. The code compiles, but in the testbench it shows that all the outputs are unknown. I tested my clock divider module, and it looks fine. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
module BCD_sevenseg(
    input clk,
    output segA, segB, segC, segD, segE, segF, segG, segDP, div_clk
    );
    
    counter module1(
    .clk(clk),
    .div_clk(div_clk)
    );
    
    reg[3:0] BCD; //BCD signal is 4 bits wide
    always@(posedge clk) //check every positive edge
        if(div_clk) //executes if counter value from module1 is true
            BCD <= (BCD == 4'h9 ? //check if BCD is at binary 9
            4'h0 : BCD + 4'h1 );
            //true: reset to 0
            //false: count up
     
    reg [7:0] sevenseg; //8 segments on 7 segment display (w/ decimal point)
    always@(*)
    case(BCD) //one case for each digit
        4'h0: sevenseg = 8'b11111100;
        4'h1: sevenseg = 8'b01100000;
        4'h2: sevenseg = 8'b11011010;
        4'h3: sevenseg = 8'b11110010;
        4'h4: sevenseg = 8'b01100110;
        4'h5: sevenseg = 8'b10110110;
        4'h6: sevenseg = 8'b10111110;
        4'h7: sevenseg = 8'b11100000;
        4'h8: sevenseg = 8'b11111110;
        4'h9: sevenseg = 8'b11110110;
        default: sevenseg = 8'b00000000;        
    endcase
    
    assign {segA, segB, segC, segD, segE, segF, segG, segDP} = sevenseg;
    
endmodule
```

Clock divider:

```
module counter(
    input clk,
    output reg div_clk=0
    );

integer count_value=0;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if(count_value == 10)//change this number to adjust output signal frequency
    begin
        div_clk = ~div_clk;
        count_value <= 0;
    end
    else
        count_value <= count_value+1;
end


endmodule
```

Testbench code:

```
module BCD_sevenseg_tb();

reg clk=0;
wire segA, segB, segC, segD, segE, segF, segG, segDP, div_clk;


BCD_sevenseg UUT(
.clk(clk),
.segA(segA),
.segB(segB),
.segC(segC),
.segD(segD),
.segE(segE),
.segF(segF),
.segG(segG),
.segDP(segDP),
.div_clk(div_clk)
);

always
#1 clk=~clk;
    
endmodule
```

[image: Testbench screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outputs are always X because `BCD` is always X.  You declared `BCD` as a `reg`, which defaults to X.  You need to initialize `BCD` to a known value, such as 0.

For simulation purposes, you can do this simply with:

```
reg[3:0] BCD = 0; //BCD signal is 4 bits wide
```

A standard way to initialize signals is to use a reset input signal.  For example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
        BCD <= 4'h0;
    end else begin
        if (div_clk) BCD <= (BCD == 4'h9 ? 4'h0 : BCD + 4'h1 );
    end
end
```